# How to completely disable caching in Symfony 4 in "PROD" environment

Tags: php, caching, symfony4

How would I completely disable caching in symfony 4 in "prod" environment set via ".env". 
I know that caching is disabled in "dev" mode but would like same to happen in "prod" mode.

Ive looked at the config yaml files and all I could find about cache was to disable the twig cache.

There is no entry under the "cache" in framework.yaml so its  pretty much empty. Ive read the cache docs here https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/cache.html and could not find any information on permanently disabling it whatsoever.

Comment: What kind of caching do you want to disable? What do you think it is cached, and at what level? There is no way to disable **all** caching. The dependency container is compiled, and even in dev is only re-compiled when needed, not on every request. Same thing with twig templates. I think you may be asking this under a misconception about what caching means in Symfony. What exactly do you believe it is cached?